# How to enable and disable backdrop static modal inside of ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem with modal backdrop static.
I tried several solutions but it doesn't work.

like removing attributes.

```
$("#loading_modal").attr( "data-backdrop" );
$("#loading_modal").attr( "data-keyboard" );
//or
$("#loading_modal").data("bs.modal").options.backdrop = true;
$("#loading_modal").data("bs.modal").options.keyboard = true;
```

Heres my code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "url",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            operation: operation
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loading_modal').modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false,
                show: true
            });
            $("#now_loading").show();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#loading_modal').modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: true,
                show: true
            });
            $("#modal_body").html(data.html);
            $("#now_loading").hide();
        }
    );
```

I just wanted is, before the ajax is send.. it will open the modal and prevent the user from closing it.
but when the ajax is successful the user should be able to close it by clicking outside of the modal.

Answer (score 0):

use this for bootstrap 4.X :

$("#loading_modal").data("bs.modal")._config.backdrop = "static";
$("#loading_modal").data("bs.modal")._config.keyboard = false;

this work for me